# ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '[35.232.51.216]' (0) in google cloud SQL client

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect my gcloud VM to a mySQL instance also on the cloud, and keep getting this errror:

ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '[10.0.0.1]' (0)

I have followed the instructions from google's documentation here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl and have not found any reasons as to why this could be happening after a lot of searching.  I have double checked that the static IP of the VM is authorized, and that I have the right IP for the SQL database.  I have tried two ways to connect, using these IP addresses and SSL.

```
    mysql --host=[10.0.0.1] --user=root --password=
```

and

```
    mysql --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl- 
    key=client-key.pem  --host=[10.0.0.1] --user=root --password=ms
```

Both return the same error and I am at a loss as to where to look.  Has anyone seen this before, or is more experienced in SQL?  This is my first time using a SQL database on google cloud...

Thanks!

Comment: It may not be secure to publish the actual IP of your MySQL instance, and I recommend obscuring when asking for help in a public platform. As to your issue, have you white-listed the IP of your VM in the Google CloudSQL console?

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to a example IP instead.  Yes I Whitelisted the IP in the Cloud SQL console, under "Authorization".  I even re-listed it a couple times to make sure but no change....

Comment: I think you should use the IP without the brackets in your command. As in "--host=10.0.0.1" not [10.0.0.1]. I really think the brackets in the example is just for notation. Can you confirm that you have tried --host=IP instead of --host=[IP]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the documentation you pointed to, the example" `mysql --host=[INSTANCE_IP] --user=root --password` is to imply that the "[INSTANCE_IP]" should be substituted for the IP of your MySQL instance. However, in the snippets above it appears, you may have substituted only the inner content of the braces (i.e. [10.0.0.1]), so try re-running your commands without the braces around your IP:

`mysql --host=10.0.0.1 --user=root --password`

Answer (score 0):

dnt add the semicolon after the  connection command like this
---> bin>mysql -u root -p -h localhost;(here) is the semicolon you just need to remove it and try it like this way..
bin>mysql -u root -p -h localhost